# When staking polkadot on the Ledger Live app, how do I select validators to avoid the error - There are no active nominations?

Tags: polkadot, staking, validator, ledger

I'm having difficulty receiving staking rewards via the Ledger Live app even after following the [best practices](https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018131260?utm_source=ledger_live_desktop&utm_medium=self_referral&utm_content=polkadot&docs=true) I am always warned - *There are no active nominations*.

[image: There are no active nominations]

In the past (~4-5 months ago), I received rewards daily, but in my recent nominations, I can't seem to figure out what mistake I'm making.

- Using https://polkadot.subscan.io/validator, I've selected only validators from the active set with ~2-3% commission.
- I've bonded more than 10 dot. ~120 which should be far above the current threshold.
- None of the nominators I've bonded with are oversubscribed.
- I maxed out my bonded set. I selected 16.

I understand the active set fluctuates, and, as shown in the picture below, some validators are now *unelected*, but I assume that if I grab of basket of 16 validators from the active set which aren't oversubscribed I should at least see some rewards.

[image: Ledger Live staking nominations]

---

Staking transaction confirmed 3 days ago.

[image: Nomination Transaction]

Does the polkadot community have any pointers for selecting validators so I can receiving staking rewards?

What am I overlooking? Maybe I just need to wait a few more days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the minimum amount to submit nomination intent is 10 DOT, the minimum nomination amount to receive staking rewards on Polkadot is dynamic and can change from era to era (each era is a day on Polkadot network). It is currently 125.43 DOT (on the day of posting this answer). You can view this value on [Polkadot staking page under the Stake tab.](https://staking.polkadot.network/dashboard/#/stake)

[image]

If you staked more than 125.43 DOT and are not receiving rewards, then the issue needs to be looked in depth. ["Why am I not getting staking rewards?"](https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000170805-why-am-i-not-getting-staking-rewards-) - this support article explains the possible reasons. If you cannot resolve this on your own, you can click on "contact us" on that support page and fill in the details. The Polkadot support team will assist you further.

PS: After the [Nomination Pools](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-nomination-pools) are deployed on Polkadot (in a few months), the minimum threshold to receive Staking rewards on Polkadot will be significantly smaller.